# Как и на каком хостинге можно запустить серверное java-приложение?

Tags: java, hosting, сервер

На каком хостинге и как можно запустить java-чат сервер? Сколько это будет стоить? Есть ли какие-то бесплатные или триальные серверы для запуска?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jelastic.com/ru/

Answer (score 3):

[Openshift](https://openshift.redhat.com) - бесплатный облачный сервис с кучей приложений.